# Unable to push to navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // 1: try loading the "Detail" view controller and typecasting it to be DetailViewController
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        // 2: success! Set its selectedImage property
        vc.selectedImage = pictures[indexPath.row]

        // 3: now push it onto the navigation controller
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I am facing issue - 
1.Cast from 'UIViewController?' to unrelated type 'DetailViewController' always fails
2.Cannot convert value of type 'DetailViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Comment: have you set "Detail" identifier in storyboard ?

Comment: Does your `DetailViewController` inherit from `UIViewController`? The error indicates that it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cast from 'UIViewController?' to unrelated type 'DetailViewController' always fails

Make sure that your `DetailViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`

```
class DetailViewController: UIVieController {
```

Also you can use another way to do that and avoid `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) method` (and avoid possible mistakes with storyboard ID): add a segue from prototype tableView cell to your view controller on a storyboard

[image]

And then configure `detailViewController` in `prepare(for segue)` method of a viewController that owns `tableView`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
        //configure vc properties here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the DetailViewController isn't a subclass of `UIViewController`. You could simply fix this issue by modifying the `DetailViewController` definition as follows:

```swift
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, keep coding.